# How do I prevent an insert from impacting the rest of my VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

Every quarter I need to input the amount of each product we have and then compare this to the previous quarter.

I need to be able to see the past 4 quarters. However, anything beyond the last 4 quarters must be kept (but not visible). So far, I've done this by grouping them. This means that if someone wants to see all of the information, they can. The most recent quarter also needs to be formatted differently to the rest (see images below).

**To keep things simple, below is a very basic example of what I'm looking for.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGdyA.png

So far, this is what I've got. However, this doesn't work perfectly because once it inserts the new column, all of the columns referenced are no longer correct:

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("B:C").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("C:D"), Type:=xlFillFormats

Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Q2_18"
Range("L1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-10]"
Range("U1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]"


Columns("G:H").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup
Columns("F:H").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
```

The main problem seems to be with the insert. In this example, I need to insert a new column before D, N and W. However, after inserting the column before column D, column N then becomes O and column W becomes X. I need to code this in a way that the insert does not have a knock on affect to the rest of the changes but I'm not sure if this is possible?

It can take the best part of an hour to format all of the tables and that's before even looking at any of the figures. Therefore, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Code between code tags not as a picture please

Comment: I am also not clear what you are trying to achieve over time? Are you adding new blocks each quarter?

Comment: Please read about providing a [mcve] and come back to us when you have a more specific and exact programming question with your code. Right now the question kind of reads like: please code this for me.

Comment: You say *I need to be able to see the past 4 quarters and anything beyond the last 4 quarters must be kept*. This is confusing. So you need just the last 4 quarters or ALL of them?

Comment: That's correct, I need to SEE the last 4 quarters (as in they must be visible) but I also need to keep anything beyond that but don't want them visible (as shown in my example).

I'm not sure how much more specific I can be. I've provided an example of what I need it to look like and the code I've currently got. What more do you need?

Comment: The main problem seems to be with the insert so let's look at that first:

In the example I provided, I need to insert a new column before D, N and W. However, after inserting the column before column D, N then becomes O and W becomes X.

I need to code this in a way that the insert does not have a knock on affect to the rest of the changes but I'm not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Adam, you have to go in reverse order when deleting/inserting.  You start with the last as to not change the column number/letter of the subsequent columns.  E.g., Insert to column 26 ("Z") makes the old Z column now column 27 ("AA")/

Answer (score 0):

Example of deletion in a loop, which should make more sense than just seeing other items inserted in individual lines of code (untested, top of head code)

```
Dim i as long, lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'dynamic last row
For i = lr to 2 Step -2 'each loop goes BACKWARDS by counts of 2
    Rows(i).delete 'every other row, from the last row until 2 is deleted
Next i
```

Had I put the above code to read For i = 2 to lr Step 1, it would increase the row number 1 for every deletion, meaning that i would first delete row 2 (makes old row 4 now row 3), then deletes old row 5 (in the 4 position), etc.

Similar if you do this for insert, you would push the other rows further down, so each insert would be in the incorrect place.

Comment: OK, so i'll insert the columns in reverse. That'll help me for this quarter. However, when I come back to it next quarter, I'll still have the same problem.

Comment: @Adam with what you're doing, the insert in reverse is the key.  Your bigger issue is finding the correct cell to insert.  You have called out specific columns, which are going to change.  You will need to dynamically determine the column to insert, for each table.  I would recommend Find or FindNext to get to the correct cells, since you're using the same set-up for each table.